# Does Google Analytics track data for bare domain if I set it up under www?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been setting up sites in Google Analytics under the www.mysite.com. Will this track visitors who type in mysite.com? (Of course, www points to host in A record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you put the analytics script in the html, it should track the domain. It doesn't really care about the exact address as long as it's the same analytics ID.

Comment: Worth noting that the URL you setup for your google analytics account doesn't actually mean anything, except that Google uses it to optionally tell you if it thinks you've installed the GA snippet correctly. By default, any page that uses the correct analytics ID will be sent and tracked in Google Analytics, regardless of the domain.